# 2 Way replication issue faced of records skipping/not replicating

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have a replication setup wherein data entry is done at head office and also at multiple branch locations; data replicates from h.o. to multiple branch locations; also data entry done at branch locations gets replicated back at h.o. location and from h.o. replicates to all branches so that each branch can see other branch data as well as h.o. data.

Many times issue faced is that a) even though; the replication monitor does not show any issue; but few records are skipped while replicating from say branch A location to h.o.

b) at other times issue faced is that even though data from say branch C comes to h.o.; it does not replicate to branch B; even though it reaches h.o. Is there a way to decipher logs that will tell which transactions/entries have not replicated at particular location. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you check if there was replication conflict ? 
If the same data is change in h.o and in branch A for example, it may look like it skip some replication but it actually keep the h.o, record instead of the A record. 
I'm assuming you are using P2P replication right

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply. There isn't replication conflict. Suppose stock requisition entry number 1225; is keyed in at branch B;it reaches to h.o.; but it does not reaches branch A from h.o.; even though it is not edited at branch B (branch which is doing the entry can only edit it). Entry number 1224 and 1126 from branch B reaches to h.o. and also at branch A from h.o.. In our setup any location data is seen at all locations. We are using transactional replication. Thanks in advance.